# Best approach to get a particular record from Corda Vault without Schema?

Tags: corda

I'm developing a CorDapp but haven't implemented the schema as it is not a good practice.

But the code I have to get a particular record without using schema is first getting me all the states and then fetching a particular record, it is very time consuming as it is iterating through over each state object.

DataFeed, Vault.Update> dataFeed = proxy.vaultTrack(IOUState.class);

```
    //this gives a snapshot of IOUState as of now. so if there are 11 IOUState as of now, this will return 11 IOUState objects
    Vault.Page<IOUState> snapshot = dataFeed.getSnapshot();
    for (StateAndRef<IOUState> state : snapshot.getStates()) {
        if (state.getState().getData().getAssetId().equals(value)) {
            cs =  state.getState().getData();
        }
    }
```

Could you please suggest better approach to fetch a particular record from corda vault without using schema and iterating through over each state object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you come to the conclusion that using a schema is not a good practice. Do you have any data points to prove this? Or the source of this information would be helpful for us to understand the problem with implementing a schema.

Is's not possible to fetch a state based on one of its attributes without a schema. However, if you are specifically interested in fetching a state based on an ID (also considering your state is Linear/ Non-Fungible in nature), you could use a linear state. A linear state can be directly fetched from the vault using a `LinearStateQueryCriteria`.

```
val criteria = LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(linearId));
val results = vaultService.queryBy<LinearState>(criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had read that somewhere that creating schema is not a good practice and the reason was if there is a need to change or add the state classes in our CorDapp then the same amount of developer efforts would go into creating or updating schemas as well for that particular functionality. Kindly correct me if i have misunderstood it. Thanks!!

Comment: Schemas have their own benefits and can't be said it's a bad practice to use it. But yes it does comes at the cost of having to update schema for state update. But it is more of an activity which is not done at a regular interval. You don't expect to do a contract upgrade at regular intervals, because even without the schema there are lot of other things you need to take care of.

Comment: I suggest you should be using schemas for certain ContactStates if your use case demands it. It's not really bad practice but in fact, a feature that could help you in many different cases like reporting and integration.

Answer (score 0):

- Who said implementing a schema is not a good practice?! Please post a link to where you read that.
- You can't get a particular record from the vault (i.e. using a query on a certain attribute) without a custom schema.